# .htaccess mod_rewrite order in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect my old webpage traffic to another while keeping some links working and pointing to same content on the new site using .htaccess RewriteRule in Wordpress.

I use pretty permalinks and while these are redirecting fine as soon as I try to redirect rest of the content they doesn't resolve.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^blog$ http://newsite.com/news/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ http://newsite.com/news/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^old-category/(.*)$ http://newsite.com/news/$1/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

The above works fine and produce proper redirects even if someone uses link like

```
http://www.myoldsite/?p=1045
```

As soon as I add something like

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com [R=301,L]
```

It produces links like this

```
htttp://mynewsite/?p=1045
```

I can't wrap my head around the order that these rules are processed. I want to let the pretty permalink generate and then if it doesn't follow the any of the above rules go to the home page under newsite.com. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=1045$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://newsite.com/tutorials? [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^blog$ http://newsite.com/news/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ http://newsite.com/news/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^old-category/(.*)$ http://newsite.com/news/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: That got rid of the problem with generating wrong link on the old site, thank you. Although the page oldsite/?p=1045 is one of the links that should be made into pretty permalink first, say the ^old-category/(.*)$ one. If there's no other solution I will just type in those id's manually.

Comment: As I thought. Going

RewriteRule ^?p=1045$ http://newsite.com/tutorials/ [R=301,L]

produces 500 server error.

Comment: You can check the query string and then redirect. See my update. If this solves your issue be sure and accept the answer.

Comment: Well it kind of worked. It redirects to a page but a different one. In our example it would be:
`http://newsite.com/news/`
I thought that it might have the same ID on the new site but it doesn't.
Should this module be above or below regular wordpress rewrite module?

Comment: Everything needs to go above wordpress rules.

Comment: It worked. I had a $ after (.*) there sorry. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can I have one more question. What does `?` do after the link?

Comment: `?` in the substitution string (rewrite URL) removes any query strings so the redirect will not carry over `?p=1045` to the new url.